# Secret Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I know that we can set up "secret" Facebook groups that people won't be able to find, but I was wondering if anyone has been able to create a secret Facebook page. I assume Facebook would probably not want to have this functionality, but it could be useful under certain conditions. Has anyone created a page like this before?

Answer (score 2):

You can not create a secret page on Facebook. This functionality is not available as of now. But you can **unpublish** you page.

Published Page is visible to the public. Unpublished Page is only visible to the people who manage the Page. Unpublishing your Page will hide it from the public, including the people who like your Page.

To unpublish your Page:

1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
2. Click **Page Visibility**.
3. Click to check the box next to **Unpublish Page**.
4. Click **Save Changes**.

Your Page won't be visible to the public until you publish it again.

**Note:** You'll need to be an admin to unpublish your Page.